# Using Blocks with Parse now Broken

Tags: ios, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I recently opened my project after upgrading XCode to the latest version. Now when auto-complete shows an option to complete a block is displays:

```
ticketQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:(nullable PFObjectResultBlock(nullable )block
```

This is very weird. I really really miss pressing 'Enter' and it creating the block syntax for me. Is anyone else seeing this or know how to get it back?

[image: Block Errors]

Thanks,

David

Comment: Have you downloaded the latest Parse frameworks?

Comment: ya I updated to 1.7.1 and still seeing this issue. Seems very strange...

Comment: Hmm, yes I have it too.  It seems they have broken something with the `nullable` stuff - there is a missing ) in the completion text.

Comment: any ideas for a work around?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669500/parse-and-xcode-blocks-wont-autocomplete

Comment: I just updated to 1.7.4 and any time I'm attempting to do anything it still gives me (nullable PFIntegerResultBlock(nullable )block instead of the block completion. Any idea what can be done? This is very annoying...