# Parse and Xcode: Blocks won't autocomplete.

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

The last version of Parse (1.7.1) and Xcode (6.3) I can't autocomplete blocks for parse API. This is really annoying. Does anyone else have this problem?

Before, like every other blocks, you can tab to highlight it, and then hit enter.

```
     [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
     {

     }];
```

Now when I hit enter, this happens:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(nullable PFArrayResultBlock(nullable )block
```

Comment: did you figure it out? Upgraded today and i'm facing the same issue ...

Comment: @DavidJirman Not yet. I'll let you know if I figure something out.

Comment: Anyone figure this out? This is driving me crazy...

Comment: just installed Xcode 6.3.2 with latest Parse framework 1.7.4 but the issue still persists

Comment: Sigh... This has been happening since 1.6. Parse is now on 1.7.4... Helloooo????

Answer (score 2):

With the new update parse took away the ability to enter and complete the block. I think that is just not good. But here is the workaround. These blocks are defined in PFConstants.h like this

```
typedef void (^PFBooleanResultBlock)(BOOL succeeded, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFIntegerResultBlock)(int number, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFArrayResultBlock)(NSArray *PF_NULLABLE_S objects, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFObjectResultBlock)(PFObject *PF_NULLABLE_S object,  NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFSetResultBlock)(NSSet *PF_NULLABLE_S channels, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFUserResultBlock)(PFUser *PF_NULLABLE_S user, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFDataResultBlock)(NSData *PF_NULLABLE_S data, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFDataStreamResultBlock)(NSInputStream *PF_NULLABLE_S stream, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFStringResultBlock)(NSString *PF_NULLABLE_S string, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFIdResultBlock)(PF_NULLABLE_S id object, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error);
typedef void (^PFProgressBlock)(int percentDone);
```

So your code would be

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *PF_NULLABLE_S objects, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error)
```

Here, ^(NSArray *PF_NULLABLE_S objects, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error) is the PFArrayResultBlock.

To make things quicker you can control click on PFUserResultBlock to find the definition and copy.

Comment: are you saying to change the definitions in PFConstants? I'm not just sure I understand how copying will help? Can't we modify the result to allow us to complete the block?

Answer (score 0):

i got it fixed, with a little change on the headers on parse, this is just temporary hacked, to make blocks work, i reset these changes once i uploaded a new build. verified this on parse 1.7.4 and xcode 6.3.2

in PFConstants.h, remove all instance of "PF_NULLABLE_S" 
and in PFQuery.h, remove all instance of "PF_NULLABLE", "PF_NULLABLE_S", "PF_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN" and "PF_ASSUME_NONNULL_END"

you will get warning "Nullability Issue" but on my testing works great, also i reset this headers back when I upload a new build.

Comment: This isn't working for me either;  it's extremely frustrating that there's not a lot of clear answers on this.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

How I went around the problem was to use the old style autocomplete `^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)`  and create a snippet. The way to create a snippet is to select the text and drag it to the snippet library (you can google it).

I know, it's not a 'Fix', but it does the job at least :)

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing it with cocoapods and autocomplete will work.

I tried importing the Parse SDK by dragging and dropping, autocomplete wont work but the code will run. But, when you add the library via pod install it will work.

see the cocoapod installtion section here

http://shaideru.com/?p=223